# How to update folderID in objects dynamically

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I’m having a requirement, where I guess I’ve to use Dynamic DML.But I’m new to Dynamic Apex as well as Dynamic DML.

When I will create a Folder in Box.com server by using API call, I will get a response with Folder ID. (Well I’m able to make the API call and able to get Folder ID)

I am having a custom field named “FolderID__c” in Account object.

So I have to write a method which will take 2 parameter .One is objecttype and other is folderID and it will do the insert operation in that particular objectType.(maybe it’s Account, maybe Contact , which should be dynamic).

### What I have done so far:

```
String IdVar = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');  //It will fetch the record ID
String objecttype = IdVar.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName(); //It will fetch object type from record ID
//By using API call I’m able to get folderID. So I’m having folder ID
public void updateFolderID(String objectType, String folderID){
   //To do
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rudra, there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :)

Comment: Do all your other objects have a FolderID__c field?  If they don't, there's nowhere to put that information.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Type class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_type.htm):

```
String IdVar = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');  //It will fetch the record ID
String objecttype = IdVar.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName(); //It will fetch object type from record ID
//By using API call I’m able to get folderID. So I’m having folder ID
public void updateFolderID(String objectType, String folderID){
  // get type
  Type t = Type.forName(objectType);
  // instantiate using the type iface
  SObject obj = (SObject)t.newInstance();
  // set field value (field must exist in the object)
  obj.put('FolderID__c',folderID);
  insert  obj;
}
```